# stdClass Object - split into table

Tags: php, arrays, object, gocardless

I am using the GoCardless API to create a subscription. I have created it and now trying to show the payments in a table.

The API returns a stdClass Object with the upcoming payments in an array. How can I show these in a table?

```
 $SUBS=$client->subscriptions()->get("$SUB");


 Subscription Class
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => SB00024BNFEEHX
    [created_at] => 2020-03-07T20:20:05.025Z
    [amount] => 5998
    [currency] => GBP
    [status] => active
    [name] => 
    [start_date] => 2020-03-12
    [end_date] => 
    [interval] => 1
    [interval_unit] => monthly
    [day_of_month] => 
    [month] => 
    [count] => 
    [metadata] => stdClass Object
        (
            [subscription_number] => 
        )

    [payment_reference] => 
    [upcoming_payments] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [charge_date] => 2020-03-12
                    [amount] => 5998
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [charge_date] => 2020-04-14
                    [amount] => 5998
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [charge_date] => 2020-05-12
                    [amount] => 5998
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [charge_date] => 2020-06-12
                    [amount] => 5998
                )
```

From other questions I have tried

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($SUBS),true);
echo"$array";
```

However this just displays/prints `Array`

Comment: You mean in an html table? Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have tried `$array = json_decode(json_encode($SUBS), true);` to no avail...

Comment: The same way you show anything else in a table… iterate over it and echo out the HTML for table cells with the escaped values you want?

Comment: @Andrea - Are you able to provide an example based on my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to convert it an `object` as `array` so simple typecast will work

```
$SUBS=$client->subscriptions()->get("$SUB");
$SUBS = (array) $SUBS->upcoming_payments;

//for table
print '<table>';
foreach($SUBS as $SUB) {
   print '<tr><td>'.$SUB['charge_date'].'</td><td>'.$SUB['amount'].'</td></tr>';
}
print '<table>';
```

Comment: This picks up everything and not just upcoming_payments. Also not in a table?

Comment: @Designer it was just for example if you want for `upcoming_payments` than pass `$SUBS = (array)$SUBS->upcoming_payments;`

Comment: But there is no need to convert it to an array.